# How to retrieve a value from an Observable to use for a service API call

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I have an Angular app using ngrx-store. I have the following files for my feature component

```
<componentname>.actions.ts
<componentname>.effects.ts
<componentname>.model.ts
<componentname>.module.ts
<componentname>.reducer.ts
<componentname>.state.ts
<componentname>.selectors.ts
<componentname>-routing.module.ts
```

I am new to both Observables and NGRX store and I need some help retrieving a value (emailAddress) from the store to then use within a service API call. In the service method I can subscribe and console log the value however when the service call is made the value is blank so I do not get the data back.

How can I subscribe to the emailAddress selector and call the service API at the same time to ensure the value is there. The email address in the store is only stored once when the user logs in, The value never changes.

My component

```
import { selectStrava } from "@app/strava/strava.selector";
import { selectEmailAddress } from "@app/core/auth/auth.selectors";

@Component({
    selector: "srm-strava",
    templateUrl: "./strava.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./strava.component.scss"],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class StravaComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    strava$: Observable<Strava>;


    constructor(private stravaStore: Store<IStravaState>) {
        this.strava$ = this.stravaStore.pipe(select(selectStrava));
        }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.stravaStore.dispatch(new GetStravaAuthorization());
    }
}
```

My component selectors

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromAppStore from "@app/core/auth/auth.reducer";
import { IStravaState } from './strava.state';

export const selectStravaState = createFeatureSelector<IStravaState>('strava');
export const state = createSelector(selectStravaState, (stravaState: IStravaState) => stravaState);
export const selectStrava = createSelector(state, (stravaState: IStravaState) => stravaState.strava);
```

My method in my API service

```
constructor(http: HttpClient, notificationService: NotificationService, appState: Store<AppState>) {
        this.http = http;
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
        this.appState = appState;               
    }

    public getStravaAuthorization(): Observable<Strava> {    
        this.emailAddress$ = this.appState.pipe(select(selectEmailAddress));
        //the following outputs to the console OK
        this.emailAddress$.subscribe(res => { console.log(res) });            
        //the email address is blank on the next call
        let getStravaApi = `${AppSettings.CONTACTS_API_HOST}employee/strava?emailaddress=${this.emailAddress$}`;
        return this.http.get<Strava>(getStravaApi).pipe(
            tap(result => console.log('getStravaAccess: executed with email ')),
            map(result => result));            

    };
```

My effect is as follows

```
@Effect()
    getStravaAuthorization$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<GetStravaAuthorization>(StravaActionTypes.GetStravaAuthorization), mergeMap(() => this.stravaService.getStravaAuthorization()
            .pipe(map((strava: Strava) => new GetStravaAuthorizationSuccess(strava))))
    );
```

The email address selector to retrieve the value from the store is

```
export const selectEmailAddress = createSelector(
    selectAuth, (state: AuthState) => {
        if ((state.userDetails === null || state.userDetails === undefined))
            return "";
        else
            return state.userDetails.email
                ;
    }
);
```

My console log is as follows

[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC4xy.png)

With code moved from the service to the component as recommended I now get an error on the this.emailAddress$ stating "could not select overload for 'new' expression type mismatch Parameter emailAddress should have type assignable to string but it has type Observable

Updated Component code

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { take } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Store, select } from "@ngrx/store";
import { GetStravaAuthorization } from "@app/strava/strava.actions";
import { Strava } from "@app/strava/strava.model";
import { IStravaState } from "@app/strava/strava.state"
import { AuthState } from "@app/core/auth/auth.model.ts";
import { AppState } from "@app/core/core.state.ts"
import { selectStrava } from "@app/strava/strava.selector";
import { selectEmailAddress } from "@app/core/auth/auth.selectors";

@Component({
    selector: "srm-strava",
    templateUrl: "./strava.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./strava.component.scss"],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class StravaComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    strava$: Observable<Strava>;
    @Input()
    emailAddress$: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private stravaStore: Store<IStravaState>, private appState: Store<AppState>) {
        this.strava$ = this.stravaStore.pipe(select(selectStrava));
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.emailAddress$ = this.appState.pipe(select(selectEmailAddress));
        this.stravaStore.dispatch(new GetStravaAuthorization(this.emailAddress$));
    }
}
```

Update Code

My Component

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.appState
            .pipe(
                select(selectEmailAddress),
                first()
            )
            .subscribe((emailAddress) => {
                this.stravaStore.dispatch(new GetStravaAuthorization(emailAddress)); //dispatch action with the payload containing email address
            });
    }
```

My Effect

```
@Effect()

    getStravaAuthorization$ = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType<GetStravaAuthorization>(StravaActionTypes.GetStravaAuthorization),
            mergeMap((action) => {
                // passing the action's payload (email address) below to service

             return this.stravaService.getStravaAuthorization(action.payload);
            },
                map((strava: Strava) => new GetStravaAuthorizationSuccess(strava)))
        );
```

My Service

```
 public getStravaAuthorization(emailAddress): Observable<Strava> {
            let getStravaApi = `${AppSettings.CONTACTS_API_HOST}employee/strava?emailaddress=${emailAddress}`;
            return this.http.get<Strava>(getStravaApi).pipe(
                tap(result => console.log('getStravaAccess: executed with emaiL address ')),
                map(result => result));
        }
```

Actions

```
export class GetStravaAuthorization implements Action {
    readonly type = StravaActionTypes.GetStravaAuthorization;
    constructor(public payload: string) { }
}

export class GetStravaAuthorizationSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = StravaActionTypes.GetStravaAuthorizationSuccess;
    constructor(public payload: Strava) { }
}
```

Something else to point out EmailAddress is not part of IStraviaState

```
import { Strava } from "@app/strava/strava.model";

export interface IStravaState {
    strava: Strava;
}

export const initialStravaState: IStravaState = {
    strava: null
};
export class Strava {
    stravaAuthorization: StravaAuthorization
}

export class StravaAuthorization {
    entityId: string;
    accessToken: string;
    refreshToken: string;
    isAuthorized: boolean;
}
```

Errors I now see with the updated code

[Component error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpWdG.png)

[effect error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBRrZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the below line, you're passing `this.emailAddress$` assuming it is the VALUE of the email address, while it is an `Observable`. Which is why it won't work.

```
let getStravaApi = `${AppSettings.CONTACTS_API_HOST}employee/strava?emailaddress=${this.emailAddress$}`;
```

I would highly recommend you to pass the email **from your component** because the service shouldn't be accessing the store for the most part.
If you still want to subscribe to the state in your service, you can do something like this:

```
public getStravaAuthorization(): Observable<Strava> {    
        return this.appState.pipe(
          select(selectEmailAddress),
          first(), // the subscription is immediately ended after retrieval
          mergeMap((emailAddress) => { // getting email address and chaining observables
            let getStravaApi = `${AppSettings.CONTACTS_API_HOST}employee/strava?emailaddress=${emailAddress}`;
            return this.http.get<Strava>(getStravaApi);

          }),
          tap(result => console.log('getStravaAccess: executed with email ')),
          map(result => result)); // you actually don't need this if you're not modifying result
        );
    };
```

### ANSWER ACCORDING TO YOUR UPDATED COMPONENT.

Please make sure your action supports a paramater named `payload`.
I.e. something like:

```js
export class MyAction {
  readonly type = MY_TYPE;
  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}
```

COMPONENT:

```js
export class StravaComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    strava$: Observable<Strava>;
    @Input()
    emailAddress$: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private stravaStore: Store<IStravaState>, private appState: Store<AppState>) {
        this.strava$ = this.stravaStore.pipe(select(selectStrava));
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.appState
        .pipe(
           select(selectEmailAddress),
           first()
        )
        .subscribe((emailAddress) => {
          this.stravaStore.dispatch(new GetStravaAuthorization(emailAddress)); //dispatch action with the payload containing email address
        });
    }
}
```

EFFECT:

```js
  @Effect()
    getStravaAuthorization$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType<GetStravaAuthorization>(StravaActionTypes.GetStravaAuthorization),
        mergeMap((action) => {
          // passing the action's payload (email address) below to service
          return this.stravaService.getStravaAuthorization(action.payload);
        },
        map((strava: Strava) => new GetStravaAuthorizationSuccess(strava)))
    );
```

SERVICE:

```js
public getStravaAuthorization(emailAddress): Observable<Strava> {  
        // assigning the emailAdress to the url's param  
        let getStravaApi = `${AppSettings.CONTACTS_API_HOST}employee/strava?emailaddress=${emailAddress}`;
        return this.http.get<Strava>(getStravaApi).pipe(
            tap(result => console.log('getStravaAccess: executed with email ')),
            map(result => result));            

    };
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried the update and still got a blank email address. I know the same emailaddress selector is working elsewhere in the app as I am displaying the emailaddress on the navigation menu. I have updated my Q to include the updated component code to include your recommendation however I now see a type mismatch error  ? If you could advise that would be great.

Comment: @JasonSargood I've added my answer according to your Updated component.

Comment: Many thanks. Updated the code as suggested but still seeing some errors. Have updated and also included some more info hoping this helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the Observable as a string value when you are building the request.

```
let getStravaApi = `${AppSettings.CONTACTS_API_HOST}employee/strava?emailaddress=${this.emailAddress$}`;`
```

There are a few ways to achieve this, I'll share the async/await route.

You can await the result of the observable by converting it to a promise with the `.toPromise()` method.

```
public async getStravaAuthorization(): Observable<Strava> {
  ...
  const emailAddress = await this.emailAddress$.toPromise();
  ...
}
```

- [toPromise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html)
- [async/await](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should select the email address from the getStravaAuthorization effect. So you dispatch: new GetStravaAuthorization() from your component without the email but the effect gets the email from your selector when its not null of undefined and pass it to our service.

```
       @Effect()
        getStravaAuthorization$ = this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType<GetStravaAuthorization>(StravaActionTypes.GetStravaAuthorization),
                 switchMap(() => this.store.pipe(select(selectEmailAddress))), 
                 filter(Boolean), 
                 mergeMap((email: string) => this.stravaService.getStravaAuthorization(email)
                .pipe(map((strava: Strava) => new GetStravaAuthorizationSuccess(strava))))
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve by updating the component as follows

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.emailAddress$ = this.authStore.pipe(select(selectEmailAddress));
        this.refreshToken$ = this.stravaStore.pipe(select(selectRefreshToken));        
        this.emailAddress$.pipe(
            skipUntil(this.emailAddress$)).subscribe(res => {
            if (res) {
                this.stravaStore.dispatch(new GetStravaAuthorization(res));
            }
        });               
    }
```